# Binding 2-dimensional collection to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, winforms

There is a two-dimensional array of double:
`private double[,] RecipesMatrix;`
I want to bind it to DataGridView. How can I do this? If it is better, I can change array to some other collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I mis-understood your question. Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BindArrayGrid.aspx which solves exactly what you want.

Comment: By two-dimensional array I meant matrix m*n (m - number of rows, n - number of columns).

Comment: Above can still be used for a m*n matrix. `m` number of `Items` and each `Item` with `n` properties. Am I missing something?

Comment: n is a variable, not constant value.